# Summation involving factorial

Tags: combinatorics

It is known that $\sum_{k = 0}^{n } {n \choose k}(k!) = \lfloor e \cdot n! \rfloor $ But is it known what $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} {n \choose k} (k! \cdot (n-k)!)$ is equal to?

Comment: I think you can use the definition of $_n C _k$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$. Therefore the given equation is equal to
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}{(n-k)!k!}=\sum_{k=0}^nn!$$

which is equal to $n\cdot n!$.